# filling combobox from database using remote object

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, actionscript, flex3

i'm just new in flex and want fill my combobox from database, this is the code, i think all is right but it doesn't work !!!
can you help be to find what i miss !!

so first this is the code of my class, it selects a column (Intitule Chapitre) from database

```
public class RapportDao {

    public Connection conectar(){
        Connection cn = null;
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=mabase;user=sa;password=sa;";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return cn;
    }   
public ArrayList<Rapport> Selection() {


             Connection conn = conectar();  
             ArrayList<Rapport> list = null;

             if (conn!=null){

                 try{
                     Rapport pr = null;
                     String a;
                     list = new ArrayList<Rapport>();
                     String sql = "select IntituleChap from Rapport";
                     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
                     while (rs.next())
                     {
                         a=rs.getString("IntituleChap");
                         pr  = new Rapport();
                         pr.setIntituleChap(a);
                         list.add(pr);
                     }

             }
                 catch(SQLException e ) {

                     // System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                     System.out.println("Error = " + e.getMessage());
                    }

             }else
             {

             }
             return list;
    }
}
```

and this is my actionscript code for combobox

```
  <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[

    import spark.components.ComboBox;
    private function getTypeprojetResult(event : ResultEvent):void
                {
                    //Alert.show(""+event.result);
                } 
    ]]>

    <fx:Declarations>
            <s:RemoteObject id="RemoteRapportDao" 
                            destination="RapportDaoDest"
                            fault="onFault(event)">
                <s:method name="Selection" result="getTypeprojetResult(event);"/>
            </s:RemoteObject>
        </fx:Declarations>

<s:ComboBox id="cmbchap" x="130" y="223" width="172" height="19" dataProvider="{RemoteRapportDao.Selection.lastResult}"/>
```

- RemoteRapportDao : is the id RemoteObject
- Selection() : my method on the service

i don't get any things on the combobox !!!
thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct but the thing you missing is calling the function from your service in before fill it.
to do that you need a listener in application complete handler

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:esri="http://www.esri.com/2008/ags"
           minWidth="1000" minHeight="700" applicationComplete="application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)">
```

this methode is called when your application is completely started.
this how you do that.

```
protected function application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    RemoteRapportDao.Selection()
}
```